# Make a plugin page out of influence of the theme's style

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, css

I have to make several change to my style to be with what i want, when i export a project to a wordpress plugins :

Based on this :

[image: Planner without Wordpress]

When including it into a plugin, i finally got this :

[image]

This output is caused by the theme.

So is there a way to prevent the css of the theme to have a influence to my planner ?

Comment: Uhhh... Okay, i've some work... Just because of a theme...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make a HTML markup out of the influence of some of the CSS loaded within the document; it is not a WordPress issue but how HTML/CSS works. The only thing you can do is to use [very specific CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in your plugin: remember that the "C" in CSS means *Cascade*.